# how I can call console Firefox screenshot within javascript?

Tags: javascript, firefox, console

Is it possible to use Firefox's screenshot function within JavaScript, there is `:screenshot --clipboard` ([link here](https://blog.nightly.mozilla.org/2018/08/23/screenshots-from-the-console)) in the console can I call it by java script ?
I try some methods but it's return with

(Uncaught SyntaxError: expected property name, got ':')

Comment: no, you can not

Comment: I know of a way to do it using html2canvas... but it actually takes a screenshot of the dom and makes it as a picture that you can append to the dom anywhere and later save as file from the browser window, once it's regularly rendered. Is it a scenario the OP can accept? or is it too far from the expectations?

Comment: I find only now about this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API/Using_Screen_Capture ... and if you need reference for html2canvas -> https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/.

Comment: I don't know where you heard of `:screenshot`. It looks like a css pseudo-selector but there's no mention anywhere. Plus you were trying to access it literally as a random property of a random object in javascript and with no concern you were using a colon inside the identifier. I'm afraid you are far from being able to handle alone this problem reading those references I shared before

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: nooooooooooooooooo.

Comment: ok finally I got your point and I regret I downvoted your question. I apologize. If you edit the question somehow it will allow me to re-upvote (I tried to add the link myself but it wasn't enough to reset that condition until the edit it's approved). I still think there's no way to send commands to the console and there's no api for such a command (think of the security concerns). But at least now it's much clearer. But the question is worth staying up in case someone will come up with a smart suggestion. I doubt about it but...